# Why can't nonempty slots be used with int, tuple, bytes subclasses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, slots

This is explicitly documented in the reference manual:

> Nonempty _*slots*_ does not work for classes derived from “variable-length” built-in types such as int, bytes and tuple.

and it is the case, writing:

```
class MyInt(int):
    __slots__ = 'spam',
```

results in:

```
TypeError: nonempty __slots__ not supported for subtype of 'int'
```

why is this, though? Why can empty slots be used but non empty ones forbidden?

Comment: Interesting. Check [this](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/python/IntSlotsPython3k) out

Answer (score 5):

`__slots__` reserves space at a fixed offset in an object’s layout for each slot defined.  (This is how it avoids having a `__dict__` in which to store them.)  A variable-length object could have a fixed-length prefix before its variable-size data, but when deriving from such a type there’s no available fixed offset at which to add a slot.  Since part of the purpose of `__slots__` is fast lookup, it doesn’t make much sense to teach it how to look past the end of the variable-length data.  `__dict__`, however, does have such support, so it’s meaningful to *suppress* it with `__slots__=()`.