# Why differences in class.__slots__ assignment via decorator vs. class body?

Tags: python, decorator, class-method, namedtuple

I'm working on a decorator to implement some behaviors for an immutable class. I'd like a class to inherit from namedtuple (to have attribute immutability) and also want to add some new methods. [Like this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578456-a-class-decorator-for-creating-named-tuples/) ... but correctly preventing new attributes being assigned to the new class.

When inheriting from namedtuple, you should define `__new__` and set `__slots__` to be an empty tuple (to maintain immutability):

```
def define_new(clz):
    def __new(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(clz, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    clz.__new__ = staticmethod(__new) # delegate namedtuple.__new__ to namedtuple
    return clz

@define_new
class C(namedtuple('Foo', "a b c")):
    __slots__ = () # Prevent assignment of new vars
    def foo(self): return "foo"

C(1,2,3).x = 123 # Fails, correctly
```

... great. But now I'd like to move the `__slots__` assignment into the decorator:

```
def define_new(clz):
    def __new(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(clz, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    #clz.__slots__ = ()
    clz.__slots__ = (123) # just for testing

    clz.__new__ = staticmethod(__new)
    return clz

@define_new
class C(namedtuple('Foo', "a b c")):
    def foo(self): return "foo"

c = C(1,2,3)
print c.__slots__ # Is the (123) I assigned!
c.x = 456         # Assignment succeeds! Not immutable.
print c.__slots__ # Is still (123)
```

Which is a little surprising.

Why has moving the assignment of `__slots__` into the decorator caused a change in behavior?

If I print `C.__slots__`, I get the object I assigned. What do the x get stored?

Comment: I'd imagine this would have to be done in a metaclass. The class body is executed before the class object exists, your decorator merely adds the attribute afterwards, but by then it is too late. Is the only reason you are inheriting from namedtuple to not allow assignment?

Comment: What made you think defining `__new__` was necessary?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385916/inheriting-from-a-namedtuple-base-class-python

Comment: That's only if you want to customize instance initialization; if you want to customize that, you have to define `__new__` instead of `__init__`.

Comment: Yeah -- turns out you're right. The issue with slots remains though...

Comment: @user48956: When you do get a non-empty `__slots__` class attribute created at the appropriate time, Python will not allow the class to be created: `nonempty __slots__ not supported for subtype of 'tuple'`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44725110/why-cant-nonempty-slots-be-used-with-int-tuple-bytes-subclasses#comment84133439_44725110

Comment: Hi, I'm curious if my answer actually helped you with the question?

Comment: It did, and thank you. It led to a lot of refactoring into hierarchies if immutable object classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code doesn't work because `__slots__` is not a normal class property consulted at run-time. It is a fundamental property of the class that affects the memory layout of each of its instances, and as such must be known when the class is created and remain static throughout the its lifetime. While Python (presumably for backward compatibility) allows assigning to `__slots__` later, the assignment has no effect on the behavior of existing or future instances.

#### How `__slots__` is set

The value of `__slots__` determined by the class author is passed to the class constructor when the class object is being created. This is done when the `class` statement is executed; for example:

```
class X:
    __slots__ = ()
```

The above statement is equivalent<sup>1</sup> to creating a class object and assigning it to `X`:

```
X = type('X', (), {'__slots__': ()})
```

The `type` object is the *metaclass*, the factory that creates and returns a class when called. The metaclass invocation accepts the name of the type, its superclasses, and its definition dict. Most of the contents of the definition dict can also be assigned later The definition dict contains directives that affect low-level layour of the class instances. As you discovered, later assignment to `__slots__` simply has no effect.

#### Setting `__slots__` from the outside

To modify `__slots__` so that it is picked up by Python, one must specify it when the class is being created. This can be accomplished with a *metaclass*, the type responsible for instantiating types. The metaclass drives the creation of the class object and it can make sure `__slots__` makes its way into the class definition dict before the constructor is invoked:

```
class DefineNew(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, dct):

        def __new__(cls, *new_args, **new_kwargs):
            return super(defcls, cls).__new__(cls, *new_args, **new_kwargs)

        dct['__slots__'] = ()
        dct['__new__'] = __new__

        defcls = super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, dct)
        return defcls

class C(namedtuple('Foo', "a b c"), metaclass=DefineNew):
    def foo(self):
        return "foo"
```

Testing results in the expected:

```
>>> c = C(1, 2, 3)
>>> c.foo()
'foo'
>>> c.bar = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

#### Metaclass mixing pitfall

Note that the `C` type object will itself be an *instance* of `DefineMeta` - which is not surprising, since that follows from the definition of a metaclass. But this might cause an error if you ever inherit from both `C` and a type that specifies a metaclass other than `type` or `DefineMeta`. Since we only need the metaclass to hook into class creation, but are not using it later, it is not strictly necessary for `C` to be created as an instance of `DefineMeta` - we can instead make it an instance of `type`, just like any other class. This is achieved by changing the line:

```
        defcls = super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, dct)
```

to:

```
        defcls = type.__new__(type, name, bases, dct)
```

The injection of `__new__` and `__slots__` will remain, but `C` will be a most ordinary type with the default metaclass.

#### In conclusion...

Defining a `__new__` which simply calls the superclass `__new__` is always superfluous - presumably the real code will also do something different in the injected `__new__`, e.g. provide the default values for the namedtuple.

---

<sup>1</sup>
In the actual class definition the compiler adds a couple of additional items to the class dict, such as the module name. Those are useful, but they do not affect the class definition in the fundamental way that `__slots__` does. If `X` had methods, their function objects would also be included in the dict keyed by function name - automatically inserted as a side effect of executing the `def` statement in the class definition namespace dict.

Answer (score 2):

`__slots__` has to be present during class creation. It affects the memory layout of a class's instances, which isn't something you can just change at will. (Imagine if you already had instances of the class and you tried to reassign the class's `__slots__` at that point; instances would all break.) The processing that bases the memory layout on `__slots__` only happens during class creation.

Assigning `__slots__` in a decorator is too late to do anything. It has to happen before class creation, in the class body or a metaclass `__new__`.

Also, your `define_new` is pointless; `namedtuple.__new__` already does what you need your `__new__` to do.